# Control source file encoding (properly read windows 1255 encoded shapefiles) in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, encoding, hebrew

My source data shapefile contains multiple attribute fields in Hebrew.

I dragged it into a new empty map in ArcGIS Pro and created a layer. The geometry and English fields of the attributes table are correctly displayed. The Hebrew ones appear as gibberish in latin characters.

I tried the same source file in QGIS. Once I set the layer encoding to Windows 1255, all fields were correctly displayed.

I don't seem to find in ArcGIS Pro any setting that allows to control the source file encoding.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000013192

Comment: Thanx for the link. The article deals with ArcGis for Desktop and does not cover ArcGIS Pro 2.5 or later. Anyway, I don't really like the idea of altering the system registry just for the purpose of one shapefile. I hope to find a simpler solution without messing with my system's gutts :)

Comment: 1) Anything that applies to old code tree should apply to the new tree 2) There are several nested links there, which includes the first option, the creation and content of a `.cpg` codepage file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by Vince's comments regarding the .cpg file, I further searched and found the very simple and effective solution. It works for my specific case but I guess it should apply for any other encoding:

**Just open a new file in a text editor, write "1255" into the first line and save it as "shapefilename.cpg" in the "shapefilename" directory (where the other .shp, .shx, .dbf, etc. files are stored)**

With the .cpg file in place, I dragged again the source file into the the map. This time ArcGIS Pro properly displayed the Hebrew fields.